# Scripting.FileSystemObject.FileExists always returns false

Tags: file-io, asp-classic

I'm attempting to check that a file exists before including it with Server.Execute in Classic ASP. While FileExists() returns False, Server.Execute successfully executes the file. Both calls use the exact same file path.

Why does this happen and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're passing a relative path (eg., "/Subfolder/Page.asp"). You'd need to [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632.aspx) that for the call into FileExists - which needs an absolute path (eg., "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Subfolder\Page.asp").

```
<%
Dim path : path = "/Admin/default.asp"
Dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fso.FileExists(Server.MapPath(path)) Then
   Server.Execute(path)
Else
   Response.Write "The path " & path & " does not exist."
End If

Set fso = Nothing
%>
```